# Does AWS CloudWatch support metric whitelisting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, metrics, amazon-cloudwatch

It looks like CloudWatch gives customers 10 custom metrics under the free plan, then each additional one costs $0.50. Does anyone know how to enforce PutMetric accept only a set of custom metrics?

I'm interested in limiting the custom metrics coming from mobile clients or possibly adding a layer of protection against abuse.

Is the only solution to implement my own service which does the validation against a whitelist?

Comment: Mmm. I was going to recommend an IAM policy that restricted `PutMetricData` calls to a specific metric name, but it appears that the Principal cannot be specified. So, no luck from that approach.

Comment: Hard to believe it's not a feature. Can you recommend alternative solutions to CloudWatch (ideally free!)

Comment: You can use Axibase Time Series Database that a) can collect both default and custom CloudWatch metrics using CloudWatch API and b) can collect custom metrics. CE is free. Disclosure: I work for Axibase. http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/writing-data/aws-integration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running a simple tomcat service which validates metrics against a whitelist (stored in s3) and publishes them to CloudWatch.

Answer (score 0):

One option you could look at is placing AWS Gateway in front of Cloudwatch and making the calls through the api.

This example shows you how to do this for S3, but there's not reason why you couldn't do something similar for Cloudwatch.

This shows you how to do it for dynamo: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/